# Choosing an IDE that is capable of running source command

Tags: c++, ide

I would like to use an IDE for debugging but prior to running the program (either debug or execute), I run a `source` command. So without any IDE, I run these commands in the terminal:

```
make
source foo.sh
./run my_args
OR
gdb --args ./run my_args
```

I tried to use Kdevelop, but I didn't find any way to tell Kdevelop to run that source command and then execute the command. I tried to use a wrapper but had no success.

So, I want to know what are the other IDE candidates. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you run source to change some envs? If this action can be done before make, you can just run `source xxx.sh && kdevelop`

Kdevelop has the ability to change envs before run/debug, just setting it in project configure.

Answer (score -1):

Use an explicit `bash -c` command to run multiple things from a single command:

```
bash -c 'source foo.sh; ./run my_args'
```

Comment: I don't have any problem when I run from terminal. My problem is with IDEs, e.g. Kdevelop.